# Pandas: group row by date, join in a single text all a column str for each day and then save them to a csv

Tags: python, pandas

Initially my data looked like this:

```
date                          str
2020-01-11 17:16:09+00:00     aa
2020-01-11 17:16:09+00:00     a  
2020-01-11 17:16:09+00:00     a    
2020-01-19 17:16:09+00:00     bb       
2020-01-19 17:16:09+00:00     bb   
2020-01-19 17:16:09+00:00     b
```

I've obtained my data frame by using:

```
df = df.groupby('date', as_index=False)['str'].apply(' '.join)
```

The df looks like this now:

```
date            str 
2020-01-11     ["aa a a"]
2020-01-19     ["bb bb b"]
```

I'd like to have different files with the date as filename and inside just a row with all the text  as a single phrase. In the end the file should looks like this:

```
2020-01-11.csv
aa a a
```

```
2020-01-19.csv
bb bb b
```

I've tried using this code:

```
df = df.groupby('date', as_index=False)['str'].apply(' '.join)

df = pd.DataFrame(df)

for index, row in df.iterrows():    
    date = str(row['date']).replace('-', '_')   
    filename = f'{date}.csv'
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding="utf-8-sig") as file:
        file.write(row['str'])
```

But I'm getting this insterad:

```
2020-01-11.csv
aa 
a 
a
```

```
2020-01-19.csv
bb 
bb 
b
```

Comment: With your first code line (`groupby`), it's not possible to obtain the input dataframe (a list of one element)

Comment: @Diana it would be better to provide the input `df` for clarity (before running the `groupby`).

Answer (score 2):

Directly use your [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object for the loop:

```
for date, group in df.groupby('date', as_index=False):
    filename = f"{date.replace('-', '_')}.csv"
    with open(filename, 'w', encoding="utf-8-sig") as f:
        f.write(' '.join(group['str'].astype(str)))
```

Output files:

`2020_01_11.csv`:

```
aa a a
```

`2020_01_19.csv`:

```
bb bb b
```

Used input for `df`:

```
         date str
0  2020-01-11  aa
1  2020-01-11   a
2  2020-01-11   a
3  2020-01-19  bb
4  2020-01-19  bb
5  2020-01-19   b
```

Comment: How `apply(' '.join)` can produce a list of one element that contains a string?

Comment: @Corralien I think the provided output is incorrect, I added the assumed input to my answer.

Comment: I've tried but I'm still getting different string in different row instead of a single string in a single row cell

Comment: @DianaMele can you provide a reproducible example? This certainly doesn't happen with your example. Are you sure there are no newline characters in your DataFrame strings?

Comment: What is the output of `df['str'].str.count('\n').sum()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
# You can replace by df['date'].dt.date if df['date'] is already a DatetimeIndex
out = df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date)['str'].agg(' '.join)
for idx, val in out.items():
    with open(f"{idx.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')}.csv", 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as fp:
        print(val, file=fp)
```

Output `2020_01_11.csv`:

```
aa a a
```

Output `2020_01_19.csv`:

```
bb bb b
```

Output dataframe:

```
>>> out
date
2020-01-11     aa a a
2020-01-19    bb bb b
Name: str, dtype: object
```

Input dataframe:

```
>>> df
                        date str
0  2020-01-11 17:16:09+00:00  aa
1  2020-01-11 17:16:09+00:00   a
2  2020-01-11 17:16:09+00:00   a
3  2020-01-19 17:16:09+00:00  bb
4  2020-01-19 17:16:09+00:00  bb
5  2020-01-19 17:16:09+00:00   b
```